# Ruby wait for a page to redirect after getting a 200 response

Tags: ruby, http, redirect

So I'm currently trying to get a `redirected URL` from one of my `original URLs`.

The problem is, when I send an `HTTP` request through ruby to one of the `original URLs`, I initially get a response with code `200` and thats it.

However, if I check it in the browser, after calling the `original URL`, it waits for a split second and redirects automatically to get a new URL. I'd like to have this new `redirected URL` from my ruby code.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Pragun Joshi, have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867652/how-can-i-get-the-final-url-after-redirects-using-ruby or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872210/get-redirect-of-a-url-in-ruby

Comment: Hello dai.  :) For some reason this didn't work for me. I'll re-check if there was anything wrong.

Comment: Howdy Pragun :)  should be pretty straight forward, have a look anyway

Comment: Can you show the code you are using?

Comment: from a little research it turns out the page i'm requesting is using a body onload function to redirect using js. so i should be closing the question i guess.